# Multi field in single query on parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Is it possible to search multiple fields on the same Class in a single query?

this is returning 0:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.startsWith("firstName", value);
query.startsWith("lastName", value);
query.find...
```

but if I search only one field I get results:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.startsWith("firstName", value);
query.find...
```

Comment: Do you want to satisfy both of the constraints or either of the constraints? In your case, you are saying that both the firstName and lastName must begin with value

Comment: I see. I want to satisfy only one of them, is it possible? Would be something like (firstName OR lastName) startsWith

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer, in case anyone need the same:

there is .or on queries:
https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_or

```
var firstQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User),
    lastQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    firstQuery.startsWith("firstName", value);
    lastQuery.startsWith("lastName", value);

var query = new Parse.Query.or(firstQuery, lastQuery);
query.find...
```